# How to Specify additional Classpath directory for jsp compilation in linux?

Tags: linux, jsp, classpath, tomcat9

I need two directories in classpath for jsp compilation, first default one in *WEB-INF/lib* no problem with this, Second one in *WEB-INF/lib1*. I'm using jars in *WEB-INF/lib1* in my jsp, so i need specify that too in classpath. After reading tomcat's [doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html), I had done some changes in **tomcat/conf/web.xml** given below but not working, got same compilation error becoz of jsp has dependency jar in *WEB_INF/lib1*.

Note: I can't copy jars from directory *lib1* to *lib*. Compiling via **wget localhost:port/jsp/a.jsp**

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>

    //changes part
    <init-param>
        <param-name>classpath</param-name>
        <param-value>../webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib1/*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    //changes part

    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```